# Find X and Y given two equal terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, fractions

***The Problem***

The two following terms are equal:

$21x^2y^5= 35x^3y^4$

*I was tasked with finding*  $\frac{x}{y}$

***What I did:***

$21x^2y^5= 35x^3y^4$

- I first divided both sides with $x^2$ which results in

$21y^5= 35x^1y^4$

- I then divided both sides with $y^4$ which results in

$21y^1= 35x^1$

- To get $\frac{x}{y}$ , I divided $\frac{35}{21}$ to result in $\frac{5}{3}$

*HOWEVER my answer is wrong*

The **correct answer is $\frac{3}{5}$**

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should look for $y/x $.

Comment: $21y=35x\implies \frac xy = \frac{21}{35}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the last equation

$$21y=35x $$
divide both sides by $35y $ to get

$$\frac {21y}{35y}=\frac {35x}{35y}=$$

$$\frac {21}{35}=\frac {x}{y}=\frac {3}{5} $$

Answer (score 0):

The last step

$$21y = 35x$$

Dividing by $35y$ 
should give you

$$\frac{21}{35}=\frac{x}{y}$$

Remark: It is also possible for $\frac{x}y =0$.